# Load jQuery tabs from Ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-tabs

I have a loading image that works using the code below. It shows the animated gif and waits for the html to be fetched from the url. Once it is fetched it hides the loading div and loads the html into the bite div. The html that is returned is all contained within jQuery Tabs however when the html is displayed the tabs are not rendered and just the li elements are shown.

Is it possible to fetch this html that contains jQuery tabs via AJAX and render these tabs? If so what am I doing wrong?

```
<div id="loader" style="text-align:center; display:none;">
<img src="img/ajax-loader.gif" alt="LOADING" />
</div>

<div id="bite"></div>

$(document).ready(function () {
  $('#loader').show();
  $.ajax({
    url:'http://www.domain.com/bitesized/main.php?uid=<?php echo $uid; ?>',
    complete: function(data){
        $('#loader').hide();
        $('#bite').html(data.responseText);
        // these divs ids are available after the load above and are meant to render the tabs
        $("#tabs").tabs();
        $("#fragment-a").tabs();
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: I can't spot anything wrong with that code. Could you perhaps verify that the `data.responseText` contains exactly the HTML you are expecting?

Comment: It does, I put an alert in and it's the right html. In any case I've solved it now. The code above works, it just took the browser cache to realise :(

Comment: On another note, perhaps you'll be interested in jQuery Ajaxy http://balupton.com/projects/jquery-ajaxy - it easily allows ajax and history support for this type of stuff - without coding twice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created this code, which can load AJAX with a spinner. Note that i set and use the option "ajax_href", which come from html rel attribute. You can also set option directly from each link. I also use "width" and "height" to resize each tab-content. looks nice, when having different content or files for the tabs.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

// check
$('.jquery_tabs_ajax').each(function() { 

    // tabs
    var $tabs = $(this).tabs({ 

        cache: false,
        ajaxOptions: { async: true, cache: false },
        show: function(event, ui) {

            // get
            var my_panel_id = '#ui-tab-' + (ui.index + 1);
            var get_panel_id = $(my_panel_id);
            var get_parent_link = get_panel_id.parents('ul:eq(0) li a[href="' + my_panel_id + '"]');
            var get_parent_rel = get_parent_link.attr('rel');

            // check options
            if(get_parent_rel) {

                // option object
                var $obj_option = {};

                // split
                $split_option_a = get_parent_rel.split(';');
                for(var so = 0; so < $split_option_a.length; so++) {
                    $split_option_b = $split_option_a[so].split('=');
                    $obj_option[$split_option_b[0]] = $split_option_b[1];
                }

                // load AJAX
                if($obj_option.ajax_href) {

                    // set spinner
                    get_panel_id.html('<div class="spinner_container"><div class="spinner"></div></div>')

                    // load AJAX
                    $.ajax({

                        type: "POST",
                        url: $obj_option.ajax_href,
                        async: true,
                        cache: false,
                        success: function(response_text) {

                            // set HTML
                            get_panel_id.html(response_text);
                        }
                    });
                }

                // check resize
                if($.colorbox && ($obj_option.width || $obj_option.height)) {

                    // resize
                    $.colorbox.resize($obj_option);
                }
            }
        }
    });
});
```

});